# How to force vim save excluded (good) words into specific file?

Tags: vimrc, spell-checking

I use two languages to check my spelling: English and Russian, so I have the following options in `.vimrc`:

```
set spell spelllang=ru_yo,en_us
set spellsuggest=10
set keymap=russian-jcukenwin
```

Sometimes I run `zG` on "incorrect" words to mark them as the "good" ones and make the exception globally. After pressing `zG` I see the following in the status line:

```
Word 'Timur' added to /tmp/vsqMS8V/10
```

It seems Vim adds my dictionary preferences/exceptions into temporary directory. Is it possible to specify concrete path where to store such files? There is `spellfile` option, but I didn't get the idea how to use it with multiple langs..

**UPDATE**

The are mistake, I should use `zg` instead `zG` to store exceptions under `~/.vim/spell` permanently and between all vim sessions. But still question is open: how to specify a concrete path/file to store the words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to mark a word as good and that vim remembers it, I think you should hit `zg` and not `zG`.

Here's what the help says about `zG` (`:help zG`) :

> zG            Like "zg" but add the word to the internal word list
>             internal-wordlist.

And here's what the help says about the internal-wordlist (`:help internal-wordlist`) :

> The internal word list is used for all buffers where 'spell' is set. 
>   It is not stored, it is lost when you exit Vim.  It is also cleared
>   when 'encoding' is set.

On my system, when I hit `zg` the word is added in `~/.vim/spell/{language}.{encoding}.add`.

If you want another location for the file, here's what the help says about the `spellfile` option :

> Name of the word list file where words are added for the |zg| and
>   |zw|  commands.  It must end in ".{encoding}.add".  You need to
>   include the   path, otherwise the file is placed in the current
>   directory.

So to choose another location for the file, type :

```
set spellfile=/path/to/your/file.{encoding}.add
```

Now, you said that you didn't get how to use the `spellfile` option to use multiple languages.

The help also says :

> For the file name the first language name that appears in
>   'spelllang' is used,  ignoring the region.

If you switch regularly between English and Russian, maybe you should try the following mappings :

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>se :setlocal spell! spelllang=en<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>sr :setlocal spell! spelllang=ru<cr>
```

They will toggle spell check and they will change the value of the `spelllang` option, which is used for the name of the file storing your exceptions.

It should allow you to have two separate files for two different languages.

Comment: After asking a question I've already guessed the mistake)) but still..even if I use `zg` how to specify a concrete file/path to store the words?

Comment: I edited the answer, I hope it will help you.